Navigation Drawer using Nav Host fragment
I am new to Android Studio and trying to create a Kotlin MVVM-based app. I want to implement a Navigation Drawer using a NavHostFragment within the app. I have defined the navigation layout containing all my different fragments to navigate. I would like to navigate to a fragment when an icon is clicked. This is the code that should allow this, but for some reason, the code doesn't work.
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    tools:context=".CentralNavigationFragment">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" />

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:defaultNavHost="true"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/central_app_navigation" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu" />


</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>




@AndroidEntryPoint
class CentralNavigationFragment : Fragment(), NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

 val TAG: String = "CentralNavigationFragment"
    lateinit var binding: FragmentCentralNavigationBinding
    private lateinit var drawerToggle: ActionBarDrawerToggle

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        val toolbar: androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar = binding.toolbar
        val drawerLayout = binding.drawerLayout
        val navigationView = binding.navigationDrawer

        // Setup Toolbar
        (requireActivity() as AppCompatActivity).setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

        // Setup ActionBarDrawerToggle
        drawerToggle = ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            requireActivity(),
            drawerLayout,
            toolbar,
            R.string.drawer_open,
            R.string.drawer_close
        )
        drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(drawerToggle)
        drawerToggle.syncState()

        // Setup NavigationView
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this)

        // Initialize NavController
        val navController = findNavController()

        // Set the default destination to HomeFragment


    }



    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        binding = FragmentCentralNavigationBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        return binding.root



    }

    override fun onNavigationItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        val navController = findNavController()


        when (item.itemId) {
             R.id.nav_home -> navController.navigate(R.id.home_navigation)
             R.id.nav_first -> navController.navigate(R.id.executedSOFragment)
            //  R.id.logout -> navController.navigate(R.id.logOutFragment)
        }
        binding.drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
        return true
    }



    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        binding.drawerLayout.removeDrawerListener(drawerToggle)
    }



<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:showIn = "navigation_view"
    >
    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_home"
            android:icon="@drawable/baseline_home_24"
            android:title="@string/home_fragment" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_first"
            android:icon="@drawable/baseline_menu_24"
            android:title="Stats metric" />

    </group>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/log_out"
        android:icon="@drawable/baseline_logout_24"
        android:title="Log out" />

</menu>





<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/central_app_navigation"
    app:startDestination="@id/home_navigation">
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/stats_user_Fragment"
        android:name="com.example.datacollector.Stats_user_Fragment"
        android:label="stats_user"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_stats_user_">

    </fragment>

    <include app:graph="@navigation/home_navigation" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/executedSOFragment"
        android:name="com.example.datacollector.ui.ExecutedSOFragment"
        android:label="executed_s_o"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_executed_s_o" />

</navigation>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/home_navigation"
    app:startDestination="@id/homeFragment">


    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/homeFragment"
        android:name="com.example.datacollector.ui.home.HomeFragment"
        android:label="fragment_home"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_homeFragment_to_SODetailFragment"
            app:destination="@id/SODetailFragment" />
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/SODetailFragment"
        android:name="com.example.datacollector.ui.ServiceOrder.SODetailFragment"
        android:label="SODetailFragment" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_SODetailFragment_to_homeFragment"
            app:destination="@id/homeFragment" />
    </fragment>

</navigation>




I want to navigate to a fragment when an icon is clicked. in my navigation layout I have a nestedGraph ,I've tried to change the startDestination on icon clicked , but the app crashes at runtime, is there any way to implement this using Navhost

Can you please add your drawer_menu and central_app_navigation code for a better understanding

I have added the following, drawer_menu, central_app_navigation and home_navigation
